How can I control which class will be inject using @AutoWired when writing unit tests?
I have a class like below
class Foo{

@AutoWired
private Bar bar;

@AutoWired
public Foo(List<Baz>){
    // do something with Baz
}

how can I control which Baz will be injected, like only injecting Baz1 instead of all classes implements Baz?
Clearly, direct call of new Foo(someBaz) won't work, as bar will be null

You can read the documentation to find out.

@MikeTung It would be appreciated if you could provide which part of documentation to read about.

@Qualifier, but your question is unclear, if you want a single Baz, why do you even inject a List<Baz>? And why are you using field and constructor injection at the same time?

@Chaosfire I wnat a single Baz in test, while multiple Baz will be injected online.

Why do you mix field injection and constructor injection? If you only use constructor injection, your problem becomes trivial ("pass the instance you want in the constructor").

@knittl Once upon a time, there was only constructor injection. Yet, another bean is required now.

@FrankBao I don't understand why you wan't add this "yet another bean" to the constructor as well? Why would the second bean be required to be field-injected?

If you've several classes that extends Baz and you want to inject only class with Baz1, you can autowire Baz1 clearly.
@Component    
class Baz1 extends Baz {

}

class Foo {
    
        @AutoWired
        private Baz1 baz1;
    }

If you've several classes that extends Baz and you want to inject all that classes, you can inject it to list field.
@Component    
    class Baz1 extends Baz {
    
    }

@Component    
    class Baz2 extends Baz {
    
    }    

class Foo {
        
            @AutoWired
            private List<Baz> allBazBeans; // Baz1, Baz2 instances
        }

